# How to detect default parameter values mismatch between the interface and implementing classes?

Tags: c#, interface, compiler-errors, default

I recently had an ugly bug whereby my collection unexpectedly had a reverse order.

```
public class WidgetContainer : IWidgetContainer
{
    // ...
    public void Add(IWidget widget, int? index = null)
    {
        if (!index.HasValue)
            _collection.Add(widget);
        else
            _collection.Insert(index.Value, widget);
    }
}
```

The calling code was not specifying the `index`. So, for all intents and purposes, this code should have been working, inserting elements sequentially.

But it didn't.

Then I looked at the interface:

```
public interface IWidgetContainer
{
    void Add(IWidget widget, int? index = 0);
}
```

Boom.

The calling code resolved the instance by interface, so `0` was used instead of `null`.

No compiler errors, no warnings - nothing. Can I enable them somewhere?

If not, can I automatically detect and prevent such issues, possibly with a solution test? Mono.Cecil, Reflection are all acceptable.

Comment: Dont call `Add` through an `IWidgetContainer` typed reference. If that's not viable, you'll need to specify the optional argument or align both optional arguments.

Comment: The default-value doesn´t seeem to belong to the methods signature, so you can omit it in your implementing class. That will not solve your problem, though.

Comment: Using a concrete type is not an option because we use IoC containers and have agreed to always resolve inteface-typed instances.

I control both the interface and the implementation, so a lot of options can be employed. I was just wondering if there was a way to automatically detect such issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Applying to an assembly:

```
Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass)
    .Select(GetDefaultParameterValuesMismatch)
    .Where(m => m.Count() > 0);

IEnumerable<(string Interface, string Class, string Method, string Parameter, object InterfaceParameterValue, object ClassParameterValue)>
    GetDefaultParameterValuesMismatch(Type type)
{
    var interfaceParameterValues = type
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .ImplementedInterfaces
        .SelectMany(i => i.GetMethods().Select(m => new { Type = i.Name, m }))
        .SelectMany(t => t.m.GetParameters().Select(p => new
        {
            Type = t.Type,
            Method = t.m.Name,
            Parameter = p.Name,
            p.DefaultValue
        }));

    var classParameterValues = type
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .GetMethods()
        .SelectMany(m => m.GetParameters().Select(p => new
        {
            Type = type.Name,
            Method = m.Name,
            Parameter = p.Name,
            p.DefaultValue
        }));

    return interfaceParameterValues
            .Zip(classParameterValues, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
            .Where(typePair => !object.Equals(typePair.t1.DefaultValue, (typePair.t2.DefaultValue)))
            .Select(typePair => (Interface: typePair.t1.Type,
                          Class: typePair.t2.Type,
                          Method: typePair.t1.Method,
                          Parameter: typePair.t1.Parameter,
                          InterfaceParameterValue: typePair.t1.DefaultValue,
                          ClassParameterValue: typePair.t2.DefaultValue));
}
```

Comment: This `!_.t1.DefaultValue.Equals(_.t2.DefaultValue)` will throw an exception if `_.t1.DefaultValue` is `null`. Better way would be to use `!object.Equals(_.t1.DefaultValue, _.t2.DefaultValue)`.

Comment: Thank you. For future readers, I would like to suggest changing `_` to a meaningful name inside lambdas. AFAIK in C# 7 `_` is commonly used as a special placeholder for *unused* lambda parameters or `out` variables.

Comment: @wh1t3cat1k You welcome. _ in more meaningful names renamed.

Answer (score 1):

> The calling code resolved the instance by interface, so `0` was used instead of `null`.

Well, yes. If the call is `someIWidgetContainerTypedReference.Add(widget);` then the call will obviously be resolved to `IWidgetContainerTypedReference.Add`.

Now, the way default arguments work is that the compiler essential converts `someIWidgetContainerTypedReference.Add(widget)` to `someIWidgetContainerTypedReference.Add(widget, 0)` *at the callsite*. Thats the key point here, optional arguments aren't "processed" inside the called method, they are directly baked into the call itself, so the optional argument specificed in `WidgetContainer.Add` is ignored altogether.

You have an extremely bad situation in your hands because your `WidgetContainer`  class is essentially "breaking" the interface contract.

The best solution? Make your class implement exactly the interface, including optional argument default values. A good question is why the compiler doesn't enforce this (IMHO it should).

Comment: "A good question is why the compiler doesn't enforce this (IMHO it should).". As of the C#-spec: "The signature of a method specifically does not include  [...] the optional type parameter constraints"

Comment: @HimBromBeere Unless I'm mistaken, type paremeter constraints are generic type constraints, so that quote is not really relevant here. Anyhow, I'm not saying the compiler isn't doing what the spec says it should (it would be a compiler bug), I'm questioning the spec itself. I'm pretty sure there are tons of good reasons why the c# team chose this behavior but it causes unfortunate scenarios like this one. There is a reason why the c# team never really wanted to implement optional arguments...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only check if the default parameters are different you can use this code:

```
var parameter = typeof(WidgetContainer).GetMethod("Add").GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "index");
var iparameter = typeof(IWidgetContainer).GetMethod("Add").GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "index");
if(!object.Equals(parameter.DefaultValue, iparameter.DefaultValue))
{
    // they are different
}
```

This can be used within unit tests and production code as well, but I would recommend using it inside of some test classes.

---

This could be done in a more generic way which could be more usefull for your case :

```
void PerformCheck(Type classType, Type interfaceType)
{
    var methods = interfaceType.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.IsOptional));
    foreach(var method in methods)
    {
       var optionalParameters = method.GetParameters().Where(p => p.IsOptional);
        foreach(var parameter in optionalParameters)
        {
            var classParam = classType.GetMethod(method.Name).GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);   
            if(!object.Equals(classParam.DefaultValue, parameter.DefaultValue))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("method " + method.Name + " has different defaul values on parameter " + parameter.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in some test application and just call the above code like this :

```
var types = typeof(WidgetContainer).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any());
foreach(var type in types)
{
    var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    foreach(var i in interfaces)
    {
        performCheck(type, i);
    }
}
```

---

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/ANN26334)

Comment: That may work for that specific case, but is quite usless in the general case, which seems to be what the OPs is asking about. You´d have to write a test for every method with optional parameters and run it.

Comment: That's just a raw idea of how to check those differences. this could be made in a more generic way ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/) extension for Visual Studio. In such case a warning with the code [RSPEC-1006](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-1006) "**Method overrides should not change parameter defaults**" would be generated.